# Can a Mecurial repository and its subrepos be cloned using --noupdate?

Tags: mercurial, mercurial-subrepos

I have a repository with a number of sub repos, and I wish to clone all of them without having working files.  When ever I try to clone using --noupdate no of the sub repositories are available in the closed repository.  Is this due to the lack of a .hgsub file in the cloned repository?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is sort of the reason why.

More specifically, subrepos are implemented not as their own repos, but as part of the working copy their parent repos ( conceptually, you can think of a subrepo as being just a single file existing in your main repo ). However as soon as you update, the repo and subrepos will be at the same state as if you had cloned without using -noupdate.